# Python 2.7.9 TLS Client Authentication

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, client-certificates, httplib

There exists a server that has a RESTful API that accepts new content via a PUT.  This service requires the client to present a valid server certificate that it uses to authenticate and authorize the data push.  Using Python 2.7.9 I created my client code based on some examples I found using the httplib and ssl modules.

This is an example of the data format that's accepted by the service.  It's an ordered dictionary because they've requested the fields be pushed in that specific order:

```
data = OrderedDict([('Title','Test Title'),
                  ('Description','Test Description'),
                  ('AlertID','1234'),
                  ('TypeName','Test_Alert'),
                  ('Properties','<tag1>Tag1</tag1><tag2>Tag2</tag2>')
       ])
```

This data is passed via a PUT as a standard query string, aka, https://host.domain/path/to/rest.php?Title=Test%20Title&Description=...

The issue I'm having is the code I created receives a 401 Authorization Required error status.  I have verified my server certificate utilizes the same CA issuer as the remote system, the CA bundles are the same on both systems, and the remote system admins have noted they've added my public key to their trusted keys chain.

This is my client code, perhaps someone can detect an issue?

```
import socket
import ssl
import httplib
import urllib

host = 1.2.3.4
port = 443
rest_url = '/path/to/rest.php'
cert_file = '/path/to/server/cert.crt'
key_file = '/path/to/private/key.key'
ca_file = '/path/to/ca-bundle.crt'

class HTTPSClientAuthConnection(httplib.HTTPSConnection):

    def __init__(self, host, port, key_file, cert_file, ca_file, timeout=None):
        httplib.HTTPSConnection.__init__(self, host, key_file=key_file, cert_file=cert_file)
        self.key_file = key_file
        self.cert_file = cert_file
        self.ca_file = ca_file
        self.timeout = timeout

    def connect(self):
        sock = socket.create_connection((host, port), self.timeout)
        if self._tunnel_host:
            self.sock = sock
            self._tunnel()

        self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file, ca_certs=self.ca_file, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    data = urllib.urlencode(data)
    conn = HTTPSClientAuthConnection(host, port, key_file=key_file, cert_file=cert_file, ca_file=ca_file)
    conn.request('PUT', rest_url, data)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    print response.status, response.reason
    data = response.read()
    print data
    conn.close()
```

I've enabled debugging as well via `conn.set_debuglevel(1)` and that's allowed me to see the headers and data going out.  The data is formatted properly and the headers, although sparse, should not cause an issue.  My original thought was it wasn't sending the correct content length, perhaps because of the dictionary, however, Content-Length seems to be set correctly and Accept-Encoding defaults to 'identity'.

I've also printed the socket wrapper to see `<SSLSocket object at 0x...>`, which leads me to believe the SSL socket was established successfully.

Finally, I've performed a tcpdump and although it's encrypted I can see parts of the cert exchange where it's verifying the issuer and whatnot, and beyond that it's all encrypted.

Beyond this, perhaps SNI?  I'd have to check with the remote server devs on that, but I know Python 2 does not support that. Perhaps I should try another route to get SSL functioning, but Im hesitant to use third-party modules because its very difficult to get this content into my environment and then maintain it, but if there is a better option with good examples let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems as though the issue could be SNI.  When I try to push data via using the same certificates I get a SSL error that the host names don't match.  I don't see that error with Python, but it just may not be catching that exception or reporting it in that manner since it seems like it has somewhat poor SSL support.

Any suggestion on fixing it if it's an SNI issue?